# Jenkins wont run my NUnit test, but cmd will

Tags: jenkins, nunit

I have been struggling with getting my Jenkins setup to run my NUnit tests.
If I use cmd to run the tests, then everything is fine.
In Jenkins I have an empty build with a build step configured to run the NUnit tests.
[image]

I then Build the test from Jenkins and everything seems fine:
[image]

And at the bottom of the Jenkins console output it looks like the test is running.. but its not!

[image]

I Then go straight to the folder where the test dll's are located and launch the cmd and run the tests. Works like a charm!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins appears to be treating your two lines as two separate commands. Ensure the two quoted strings are just separated by a space, and not a line-break.

You can tell this from how the command are written in your Jenkins output - everything you have there should be one command, not two separate entries. The reason you are seeing some NUnit output - is that if you run nunit3-console with no parameters, you get the list of options it takes printed to console.

Comment: Tried that but that dosent work either. I just get a "Syntax error in either filename, folder og disk name".

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyFirstJob>"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe C:\Users\thore\source\repos\OJv4PC\NUnitTests\bin\Debug\NUnitTests.dll"

Comment: @Christian - you need to keep both filenames quoted, as you had originally, but just have them separated by a space, rather than a line break, as I _think_ you must have done originally.